# Unable to install .ipa from apple configurator 2 and xcode

Tags: xcode, react-native, build, apple-configurator, ios-standalone-mode

This is my first app to try to distribute, a beginner here. Please help me

I have created an app with Expo React Native and wanted to distribute it to my friends for testing. I generate the .ipa file with the command below.

```
expo build:ios
```

Expo request for my credentials and some other details when I run the command above and I leave everything to the expo to handle the documents.

With the generated .ipa file above, I use Apple Configurator 2 to install my app, simply “add”>“apps”>“Choose from my mac”>select .ipa. The app appears in iPhone but darker colour and show "Unable To install ‘app-name’. Please try again later. " when I click it. Tried to install with Xcode as well but fail too.

Then I found someone able to solve this issue by register his iPhone’s UDID to the account. Done it but doesn’t work.

I have also created Ad Hoc Provisioning Profile and run it with the command above. For some reason, errors appear and fail to build my app to generate an .ipa file with it.

What should I do? Feel free to ask for more information. Can somebody help me to publish a standalone app with expo react native? What are the requirements? I want to install it on my phone only, not for public or commercial use.

One extra information, I have also downloaded a random .ipa file from the random website for testing. The result is failing to install as well. Same error.

Comment: Hi Kenneth, did you fund any solution ?

Comment: Hi, JenJose. Sorry for late reply. 
I didn't solve it. But I found my solution that works for me, I create a share account on Expo and everyone opens the app via Expo on phone

Comment: Thanks Kenneth ! My issue was something different, I was trying to install an app build using a Distribution profile. It won't work, it has to an Enterprise Distribution profile to allow a direct install.