# How do i build standalone apps that users can open it without Expo client

Tags: ios, react-native, distribution, expo

@brentvatne,

I have a `React Native` code for iOS and it works perfectly on `expo` cli. But I keep getting errors when I `expo eject` it out and run on Xcode, or unable to install the .ipa file with `expo build: ios`. Every method I tried doesn't work.
Then I saw your answer to the post, ["What is the difference between Expo and React Native?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39170622/what-is-the-difference-between-expo-and-react-native) and you mention it below.

> if you publish it through expo-cli, people can access it at any time through the Expo client on Android or on iOS if signed in to the same account

and

> we also make it possible to build standalone apps so people don't have
>   to use the Expo client to open it

I just want my app to be distributed among 20 people and not planning to upload to App Store. In-House distribution is what I need. I have also posted regarding unable to install .ipa into my phone
[my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59136475/unable-to-install-ipa-from-apple-configurator-2-and-xcode),
but still unsolved. Could you advise the easiest way to distribute my app? I need a way to install/access the app to iPhones anywhere (Not like TestFlight only 90 days) and easy to update once there is an update.

Hopefully, you will read my post. Anyone who always has the answer as well, please guide me. Thank you all in advance.

Cheers

Comment: The ideal one is to subscribe to the enterprise account (you need at least 100 employees in your company) and use in house distribution... Since you mention that you just need it for 20 people and you don't want more than 90 days lifetime for the app..You can use ad-hoc distribution which will give you lifetime of up to a year...

Comment: You have to build Apk file from your code and that apk file is used anywhere you can install that anywhere in any device.

Comment: @user1872384, I know about Ad-Hoc distribution, but failed as well. You may see [my post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59136475/unable-to-install-ipa-from-apple-configurator-2-and-xcode).

Comment: @AnujSharma, I'm building an app for iOS, so it would be ipa file. I have no problem generating apk file. Unless it is possible to install apk file into an iPhone.

Comment: Check the answer below and do upvote if it helps you anyway

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can also gernate ipa file  but you need Mac for this , There is no possible way to create IPA file from windows. If you have Mac then check this example it will let you know how to gernate ipa .

https://medium.com/better-programming/create-ipa-and-apk-from-react-native-72fe53c6a8db

Hope it helps .feel free for doubts.